# String to time convert in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

my string is like this

```
shedule_time = {
start_time : "13:00",
end_time : "14:10"
}
```

now change to time in mongodb

```
i used dateFromString but its not working
```

The aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('appointments').aggregate( [ 
{ "$addFields": { "date": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$schedule_time.from", "format":"%H%M" } } } } 
] )
```

The error:

```
error assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: format", "code" : 40541, "codeName" : "Location40541" } : aggregate failed _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13 doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14 assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5 DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5 @(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Please post the code you had tried, _and_ the error (if any) or the result you got (if any). Also, what is the expected result; an example.

Comment: db.getCollection('appointments').aggregate( [  { "$addFields": {
        "date": { 
            "$dateFromString": { 
                "dateString": "$schedule_time.from",
                "format":"%H%M"
            } 
        }
    } } ] )

Comment: error

assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: format",
 "code" : 40541,
 "codeName" : "Location40541"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1

Comment: You can convert a string (with date and time info) to a `Date` field. MongoDB stores date as [Date datatype](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date). The date has both the date+time information; see [Date in mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#date).

Comment: date having bro

Comment: shedule_date field

Comment: how to concat two field and convert to utc format

Comment: You can use the aggregation's `$concat` operator, _and_ then use the concatenated date+time string to a date data-type using the `$dateFromString` operator.

Comment: @vicky : `shedule_time = {
start_time : "13:00",
end_time : "14:10"
}` As these are just particular times in a particular day, just store those as numbers `1300` & `1410` & from your code pass input as `1350`, or at least pass input as `1350` & convert `'13:00'` & `'14:10'` to numbers in aggregation each time(I would prefer write in correct way rather than converting in every read), that is ideal converting `13:00` to time is not correct as time/date  needs a day you can say which day is from that field !!

Comment: @vicky What exactly are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: `"Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: format"` - the `format` argument is not availble in MongoDB 3.6

Answer (score 0):

i solve this question

```
db.collections.aggregate([  
                    { 
                    "$project": {
                    "doctor":1,
                    "dates":{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$schedule_date" } },
                    "from":{
                            "$dateFromString": { 
                                "timezone": "+05:30",
                                "dateString":  {"$concat": [{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$schedule_date" } },
                                {  "$concat": ["$schedule_time.from", ":00"] } ] },
                            }
                     },
                      "to":{
                            "$dateFromString": { 
                                "timezone": "+05:30",
                                "dateString":  {"$concat": [{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$schedule_date" } }, 
                                {  "$concat": ["$schedule_time.to", ":00"] } ] },
                            }
                     }
                    },

                    },{
                    $match:{
                     $and: [{
                        "doctor": ObjectId(obj.doctor)
                    }, 
                    {
                        $or: [
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        from: {
                                            $gte: new Date(from)
                                        }   
                                    },
                                    {
                                        to: {
                                            $lte: new Date(to)
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        from: {
                                            $gte: new Date(from)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        from: {
                                            $lte: new Date(from)
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }, {
                                $and:[
                                    {
                                        to: {
                                            $gte: new Date(to)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        to: {
                                            $lte: new Date(to)
                                        }
                                    }
                                ] 
                            }
                        ]
                    }]

                 }
            }
        ])
```